# SQL query to identify result using self join or any other way

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table like below:

```
ID  Name    ManagerID

1   Dave       NULL

2   Scott       1

3   Mike        1

4   Nick        3

5   Jack        1
```

How Can I find out corresponding Manager Name of all the employee, something like below format?

```
ID  Name    ManagerID   ManagerName

1   Dave    NULL        NULL

2   Scott   1           Dave

3   Mike    1           Dave

4   Nick    3           Mike

5   Jack    1           Dave
```

Comment: You need an additional table of ManagerId->ManagerName mapping, and then just do a JOIN

Comment: @Lavi Avigdor No, he doesn't - the mapping is already in his employee-table.

Comment: Understood. Didn't see it like that. So an employee is also a possible manager. makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
select a.ID,a.Name,a.ManagerID,b.Name as ManagerName 
       from #t a left join #t b on a.ManagerID=b.ID
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5389)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Name, ManagerID,
       (case when managerid is null then null else (select Name from tab where id=managerid) end) as ManagerName
from tab
```

You can do this way too

Answer (score 0):

Possible in several ways. 
Such as:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Name, ManagerID, 
    (SELECT Name FROM table AS ManagersTable WHERE ManagersTable.ID=EmployeesTable.ManagerID) AS ManagerName
FROM table AS EmployeesTable
```